# How to put data from a big file into a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, file, memory, io, pandas

Usually when I want to put content of a file in a data frame I make a loop over the lines of the file, split the lines into the fields and use this values to specify a dictionary. After reading one line I append the dictionary to a list (so, the number of dictionaries in the list is equal to the number of lines in the file). Then I use the list of dictionaries to construct a data frame.

Unfortunately this approach failed for a big file. After 600 thousands line of the file my python script becomes very slow and my Ubuntu hangs.

I assume that it happens because appending a new element to a huge list becomes slow and a lot of memory is used. Are there a better way to extract information from a file to a data frame?

Comment: Have you tried pandas read_csv? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html